# Group Date column and display it as a date range based on grouping another column and only group if the next row has same value of grouping

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to group date column and display it as a date range. This grouping , however is based on 2 different non-date grouping columns. I am trying to do this in SQL Server Management Studio.
I tried a lot of methods but either the method is not working or grouping everything together by either columns. Below is an attached image which shows the input and the required output.
Below are the input and required output tables.
Please help me out with this.

Input Table-
| ID       | Grouping Col 2 | Census date |
| -------- | -------------- | ----------- |
| 1        | Block-1        |   7/2/2022  |
| 1        | Block-1        |   7/3/2022  |
| 1        | Block-1        |   7/4/2022  |
| 1        | Block-2        |   7/5/2022  |
| 1        | Block-2        |   7/6/2022  |
| 1        | Block-2        |   7/7/2022  |
| 1        | Block-2        |   7/8/2022  |
| 1        | Block-1        |   7/9/2022  |
| 1        | Block-1        |   7/10/2022 |
| 1        | Block-1        |   7/11/2022 |
| 1        | Block-1        |   7/12/2022 |
| 1        | Block-1        |   7/13/2022 |
| 2        | Block-2        |   9/14/2022 |
| 2        | Block-2        |   9/15/2022 |
| 2        | Block-3        |   9/16/2022 |
| 2        | Block-3        |   9/17/2022 |
| 2        | Block-3        |   9/18/2022 |
| 2        | Block-3        |   9/19/2022 |
| 2        | Block-3        |   9/20/2022 |
| 3        | Block-2        |   10/21/2022 |
| 3        | Block-2        |   10/22/2022 |
| 3        | Block-1        |   10/23/2022 |
| 3        | Block-1        |   10/24/2022 |
| 3        | Block-2        |   10/25/2022 |
| 3        | Block-2        |   10/26/2022 |

Output Table-
| ID       | Grouping Col 2 | Start Date  | End Date  |
| -------- | -------------- | ----------- | --------- |
| 1        | Block-1        |   7/2/2022  | 7/4/2022  |
| 1        | Block-2        |   7/5/2022  | 7/8/2022  |
| 1        | Block-1        |   7/9/2022  | 7/13/2022 |
| 2        | Block-2        |   9/14/2022 | 9/15/2022 |
| 2        | Block-3        |   9/16/2022 | 9/20/2022 |
| 3        | Block-2        |   10/21/2022| 10/22/2022|
| 3        | Block-1        |   10/23/2022| 10/24/2022|
| 3        | Block-2        |   10/25/2022| 10/26/2022|

[Required Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8yGVZ.png)

[Input and Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDsVV.png)

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: "I tried Recursive CTE . LAD , Lead methods, Partition by methods" - well we can't tell you if you are doing it wrong unless you show us what you tried.

Comment: FYI SSMS is not relevant to your question, SSMS is purely a client UI and has no part in running the query.

Comment: Please read: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Try gaps and islands

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution to this. Below is the code for same. The code is in a Create view statement.
Answer-

```
    CREATE VIEW YourViewName AS
    SELECT
    ID,
    [Grouping Col 2],
    MIN([Census date]) AS [Start Date],
    MAX([Census date]) AS [End Date]
    FROM (
        SELECT
        ID,
        [Grouping Col 2],
        [Census date],
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY [Census date]) -
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, [Grouping Col 2] ORDER BY       
    [Census date]) AS grp
    FROM YourInputTable ) AS subquery
    GROUP BY ID, [Grouping Col 2], grp;
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?